# Design: List storing objects; access information associated with that object

Tags: c#, list

I have two classes that are pertinent to what I'm trying to do.

Class 1: Person

Class 2: Personal Profiles

Person has properties such as address, name, phone #, etc...

Inside of my Personal Profiles class I have a List that stores the information for the Person's that have been created.

My question: If I'm trying to find out whether a Person with address: 999 Candy Lane exists within the List do I need to create a a new Person with default's for everything except the specified address and then use that in my .Exists or .Contains? Or should I not be creating a new object just for a searching function.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results? Were they not what you expected? I think maybe a little effort is in order.

Comment: It was really just a design question; is it acceptable 'coding practice' to create a temporary object to only be used for comparison sake, or is that taboo.

Comment: Designs questions are not taboo per se, but should require a little bit of effort. Maybe something along the lines of "Here's what I've written, how can this be improved? is this good practice?"

Comment: @CAbbott A question in that form would belong on CodeReview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use Linq:

```
theList.Where(x => x.address == "999 Candy Lane").First();
```

Comment: Just to note: if the person is not found an exception is thrown. You should not use exception to control flow

Comment: Yes. He can use FirstOrDefault() as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, yea I was completely over-complicating the matter trying to make an object..  I think I was confused on how to single out the specific properties, but this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you use .net 3.5+ you can use a linq query:
i.e.

```
var result = (from p in Profiles where p.Address=="bla bla" select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

The result will be null if no matching person is found.

Answer (score 1):

Given the high probability of missing values it is better to use FirstOrDefault.
Of course First and FirstOrDefault takes a predicate so there is no need to use Where

```
var result = List.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address == "999 Candy Lane"); 
if(result != null)
{
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact use case for [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx).

It is used like this:

```
if(People.Any(p => p.Address.Equals("999 Candy Lane")))
{
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to create a new object for searching:

```
Person person = profiles.PersonsList.Where(p => p.Address == "Address here")
                                    .Select(p => p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use linq and a lambda:

```
var candyLane = Persons.Where(x => x.Address == "999 Candy Lane").ToList();
```

What this does is supply a lambda predicate to be used as a selector. Think of it like an anonymous function specified like this:

```
public bool CandyLaneChecker(x){
    return x.Address == "999 Candy Lane";
}
```

Where the braces and return keyword are replaced by a `=>` and the `public bool CandyLaneChecker` is omitted because this is an anonymous function. That would leave `(x) => x.Address == "999 Candy Lane"` and we could've left the parenthesis in our original predicate, but they're not needed.

Alternately, one could use a linq expression such as:

```
var candyLane = (from p in persons
                 where p.Profile.Address == "999 Candy Lane"
                 select p).ToList();
```

Which looks a lot more like a database query and is easier for some people to understand.

The great part about the linq expression is that you could even use that same expression with XML.